# How to show multiple font colors inside the Text Field

Tags: css, textbox, textfield, required-field

i want text inside the text field like "your name* "
the color of "your name" should be black and the color of * should be red.
how can i do this??

Please help me.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't partially change text color in a text field or a text area. You'll need to look into using contenteditable attribute and copy the contents from it to a text field to store value (like what most WYSIWYG editors do)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what i was asking here in question.
Multiple Colors Placeholder. 
[Answer Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907031/is-it-possible-multiple-text-color-in-a-single-placeholder<br)

Some Trick here

```css
.input-field {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.input-field > label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.input-field > input[type=text]:focus + label {
    display: none;
}
.input-field > label > span {
    letter-spacing: -2px;
}
.first-letter {
    color: red;
}
.second-letter {
    color: blue;
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
    <input id="input-text-field" type="text"></input>
    <label for="input-text-field"> 
        <span class="first-letter">your name</span>  
        <span class="second-letter">*</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot; the value of a text input field is plain text.

Put the explanation, including the requiredness indicator if desired, in a label, not into the field. The you can use markup for the indicator, and color it:

```
<label for=name>Your name<span class=reqd>*</span>:</label>
<input id=name name=name size=40 required>
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. my designer gave me the design of page that contains this type of text fields as i mentioned above in my question.This was the new thing for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have different colours in one text box. (Reliably across browsers anyway)

The most common approach to this issue for required fields is to place the asterisk directly after the text box in an element with a class to set the text to red.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JzFd4/

Comment: i want circle hover on my image.
it is the image of resolution 230 x 231.when hover on image, it will be shown only circle part.

how it will be?

Comment: Create a new question with your problem and the whole community will be able to offer help :)

Comment: i created the newer one but system told me that It does not meet our quality standards. :(

Comment: Don't let it put you off, try again including as much information & code as possible. Have a go at what you are trying to achieve and ask about the bits you are stuck on. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you should want this

**CSS**

```
label{
    color:black;
}
label  span {
    color:red;
}
input{
    line-height:25px;
    color:gray;
    font-size:16px;
}

input:focus{
color:black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label>
    Your Name:- <input type="text" value="your name"><span>*</span>
</label>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/dZmaZ/

Comment: ma ne kuch din howe join kiya he ye network. bhot achi site he ye.