# Is it possible multiple text color in a single placeholder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a placeholder with multiple color text.Is it possible 
please help me.

I have a input text filed where placeholder showing I'm a good boy.
I want good word different in color.

Comment: use the `span` tag for this

Comment: with placeholder you cannot achieve this.you cannot add span elements in placeholder attribute of input element.

Comment: Like @Bhadra said, with placeholder attribute you can't achieve this. But with a placeholder technique yes. If you fake the placeholder (like puting an overlaped span on the input that hides when clicked) you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @Bhadra and frikinside
I got both of your point

Comment: Do you mean like this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sd2kayex/)

Comment: Maybe you can adapt the fiddle in this question to work with the placeholder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994408/jquery-wrap-every-nth-word-in-a-span

Comment: Yes visually like this.
but only through placeholder 
@Mr_Green 
But your way I can do this

Comment: @Rvervuurt that's also good. But I found easy solution Mr_Green way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to color the default placeholder but you can create a element similar to placeholder. So, that you can color the letters. This is a workaround to the default placeholder.

Note that I am using `opacity: 0.5`, you can change it as per your need.

---

<strike>**HTML**</strike>

```css
.input-field {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.input-field > label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.input-field > input[type=text]:focus + label {
    display: none;
}
.input-field > label > span {
    letter-spacing: -2px;
}
.first-letter {
    color: red;
}
.second-letter {
    color: blue;
}
.third-letter {
    color: orange;
}
.fourth-letter {
    color: green;
}
.fifth-letter {
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="input-text-field" type="text"></input>
        <label for="input-text-field"> 
            <span class="first-letter">H</span>  
            <span class="second-letter">E</span>
            <span class="third-letter">L</span>
            <span class="fourth-letter">L</span>
            <span class="fifth-letter">O</span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

<strike>**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sd2kayex/1/)**</strike>

---

## Updated:

#### Only CSS (*with `:placeholder-shown`*)

**The above fiddle has a bug** which is when you type something in the textbox and click outside, the placeholder is visible again above the entered text.

So, to make it perfect, we can use [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) which hasn't have much support yet other than chrome and firefox.

Here is the code:

```css
.input-field {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-field > label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: none;
}

.input-field > input[type=text]:placeholder-shown + label {
  display: block;
}

.input-field > label > span {
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}

.first-letter {
  color: red;
}

.second-letter {
  color: blue;
}

.third-letter {
  color: orange;
}

.fourth-letter {
  color: green;
}

.fifth-letter {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <input id="input-text-field" type="text" placeholder=" "></input>
  <label for="input-text-field">
    <span class="first-letter">H</span>
    <span class="second-letter">E</span>
    <span class="third-letter">L</span>
    <span class="fourth-letter">L</span>
    <span class="fifth-letter">O</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/sd2kayex/9/)**

#### Using JS (*without `:placeholder-shown`*):

```js
addListenerMulti(document.getElementById('input-text-field'), 'focus keyup', blurme);

function blurme(e) {
  var element = e.currentTarget;
  element.classList[(element.value.length !== 0) ? "add" : "remove"]('hide-placeholder');
}

function addListenerMulti(el, s, fn) {
  s.split(" ").forEach(function(e) {
    return el.addEventListener(e, fn, false)
  });
}
```

```css
.input-field {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.input-field > label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.hide-placeholder + label {
  display: none;
}
.input-field > label > span {
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}
.first-letter {
  color: red;
}
.second-letter {
  color: blue;
}
.third-letter {
  color: orange;
}
.fourth-letter {
  color: green;
}
.fifth-letter {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <input id="input-text-field" type="text"></input>
  <label for="input-text-field">
    <span class="first-letter">H</span>
    <span class="second-letter">E</span>
    <span class="third-letter">L</span>
    <span class="fourth-letter">L</span>
    <span class="fifth-letter">O</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/sd2kayex/10/)**

Comment: This does not color a placeholder. It is based on not using an HTML placeholder at all and instead constructing something that has similar appearance. It also creates an accessibility problem by placing letters after the input field.

Answer (score 0):

CSS could help you (not IE yet). `mix-blend-mode` + `gradient` and `background` dispatch in 2 containers.

i used `required` (attribute) and `:invalid` (CSS) to trigger effect only when `placeholder` is shown.

For info , take a look at :

Example (for browser that deals with `mix-blend-mode`)

```css
input {
  font-family:monospace;
  vertical-align:middle;  
  font-size:2em;
}
input:invalid {
  mix-blend-mode:screen;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px black,0 0 1px black,0 0 1px black,0 0 1px black,0 0 1px black; /* increase visibility */
}
label {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right, 
    pink 10%,
    blue 10%,
    blue 20%,
    purple 20%,
    purple 30%,
    red 30%,
    red 40%,
    green 40%,
    green 50%,
    turquoise 50%,
    turquoise 60%)
  left  ;
  background-size: 10em 400px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label><input type="text" required placeholder="show me colors"/></label>
</form>
```

[image: supposed to be showing if mix-blend-mode implemented]
another example with image backgrounds and gradients still in use : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WwgzVv