# Change placehloder font color in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My current output is like below:

[image: My current output is like this]

I want to change asterix sign color (*) in placeholder, I want output to look like this:

[image: I want need output look like]

How to do this using jQuery or CSS?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Thanks @SidharthGusain i think its work for me

Comment: Thanks @Mr_Green for answer , yes you understand my requirement..

Comment: @SidharthGusain Thanks for pointing [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25907484/1577396). I updated it now with more perfect fiddle :)

Comment: if my question is valid then plz any one vote my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".lab").on("click",function(){
    $("#txt").focus();
    })
  
  $("#txt").on("focusout input",function(){
    if($(this).val() == '') {
      $(".lab").css({display:"block"});
      $(this).css({backgroundColor:"rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.3)"})
        }
    
    else {
      $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#fff"});
      $(".lab").css({display:"none"});    
        }     
    })     
})
```

```css
.d {
  position: relative;
}
#txt {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
.lab {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
.star {
  color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<h3>Normal placeholder</h3>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name*">
<h3>My placeholder</h3>
<div class="d"> 
  <input type="text" id="txt" >
  <div class="lab">
    <span class="name">Name</span>
    <span class="star">*</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ehsan still it is same. nothing happens when I click on placeholder text.

Comment: @Mr_Green ,in placehpder when content must be hidden , you type something no when you click on it.write `<input type="text" placeholder="Name*">` in your editor and click on it.and see result.

Comment: @ehsan I understand that and edited my answer. Thanks. But I was talking about your answer. when I click on the placeholder text, I am unable to get focus on the textbox.

Comment: This answer does not work. The placeholder is not hidden when you click on the input.

Comment: @Cerbrus , in placehpder when content must be hidden , you type something no when you click on it.write `<input type="text" placeholder="Name*">` in your editor and click on it.and see result.

Comment: @ehsan why are you hanging with the same use case which I already fixed when you said? Cerbrus (and I before) are trying to explain you the different use case, which you haven't covered. Now re-read the comments.

Comment: @Mr_Green , ok ,i fix it.Thanks.

Comment: @Cerbrus , Thanks , i fix it.

Comment: @ehsan: Why are you mangling the snippets like that? Use the proper fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #909;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #909;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to change only * sign color not full place holder text color

Comment: You can just wrap that in a span like <span>*</span> and provide a class to it. That can be done with jquery

Comment: but when i add <span>*</span> in placeholder then input box is not display in page

Comment: Can't style different color to text using placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[placeholder], [placeholder], *[placeholder] {
   color: #333333;
}
(or)
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #333333; opacity: 1 !important; }
:-moz-placeholder { color: #333333;}
::-moz-placeholder {color: #333333;}
:-ms-input-placeholder {color: #333333;}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to change only * sign color not full place holder text color

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".